# SecurityException when trying to query uri associated with third party application like ES File explorer

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-fileprovider, file-manager, android-securityexception

I am getting SecurityException when trying to query uri associated with third party application like ES File explorer.However everything works fine when trying to query uri from device's default file manager

1.Open gallery to pick video.

```
 private void uploadVideo() {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

2. From slide menu select ES File Explorer.
3. I get crash on below line-

   ```
     Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null,null, null, null);
   ```

Crash-

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.estrongs.files/storage/emulated/0/video1599727800557.mp4 }} to activity {xyz/xyz}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.estrongs.android.pop.app.FileContentProvider from ProcessRecord{454561a 26743:xyz/u0a365} (pid=26743, uid=10365) that is not exported from UID 10170
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4596)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4638)
       at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1976)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221339/discussion-on-question-by-android-developer-securityexception-when-trying-to-que).

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( uri.toString.startsWith("file://")
    return uri.toString().replace("file://", "");
```

And for the rest

```
try {
 // doing all kinds of nasty things like trying to get real path from uri and such
 // which sometimes seem to work for Android below Q but never for Android 10 and 11.
}
catch (SecurityException e) {     
    // if ( uri.getAuthority().equals("com.estrongs.files")) 
    //     return uri.getPath(); 
     
    if ( new File(uri.getPath()).exists() )
         return uri.getPath();     
    
    return null; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..u r using two return statements..so if its from estrongs we can return uri.getPath(); without checking whether file exist or not?If any other third party application we need to check!

Comment: if uri starts with a file then we should not use getpath()?..I think that check can also be posted inside catch block?

Comment: I have tested your code and it seems to have resolved crash and working fine.Will accept it once tested thoroughly.I am not using authority check since it seems to be not required and u have also commented it out!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to create solution from the comments i received for Handling Security Exception when getting a file path from a Uri.Below code is not tested in different devices.Feel free to post comments!

```
 catch (SecurityException e) {
            //if file open with third party application
            String finalPath;
            if (uri.toString().contains("/storage/emulated/0")) {
                finalPath = "/storage/emulated/0" + uri.toString().split("/storage/emulated/0")[1];
            } else {
                finalPath = uri.getPath();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(finalPath) && !finalPath.startsWith("/")) {
                    finalPath = "/" + finalPath;
                }
            }
            return finalPath;
        }
```